# How to create command to create a role | discord bot

Tags: discord.js

I am creating a bot for discord and I try to create a command to be able to play a role, already in several places but I can't understand it well

```js
guild.createRole({
name: 'role',
color: 'RED'
});
```

putting this code tells me "guild is not defined"
if you could help me I would be very grateful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define the guild to be able to call methods on it. Here are a few ways you can define the guild and create a role

1. Retrieve the guild from a message

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('message', (message) => {
  let guild = message.guild;
  guild.createRole(...) ///put in your data here
    .then(role => console.log(`Created new role with name ${role.name}`)) //What to do when it has been created
    .catch(console.error); //Handle an error
}
```

2. Get the guild from guild id

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on("ready", () => {
  let guild = client.guilds.get("GUILD-ID");  //Replace "GUILD-ID" with the id of the guild you want
  guild.createRole(...) ///put in your data here
    .then(role => console.log(`Created new role with name ${role.name}`)) //What to do when it has been created
    .catch(console.error); //Handle an error
}
```

Comment: client.guilds is only available after client#ready fired. Wich in your 2nd case is not checked.

Comment: Thanks @PLASMAchicken, i've updated the answer to reflect this